# Need to ignore "start with" sequence for identity column when comparing schema in oracle db

Tags: oracle, compare, schema

We have an oracle database (18c) on several servers, and need to sync the schema from dev to prod servers. Since it is only the schema that needs to be synced, and not the content of the tables, we do not need to know the next sequence number of primary key columns. (And we certainly do not want to update the prod servers with this sequence number.)

Have tried both SQL Developers Diff Tool and dbForge Schema Compare for Oracle, but they both list tables where only this sequence number is different as tables that need to be updated.

I have not found a setting in SQL Developer Diff Tool that handles this. In dbForge Schema Compare for Oracle they have the `Ignore START WITH in sequences`, but this seems to not work as I thought, since it still marks tables that are equal except for the sequence number as tables that need an update.

For new tables that only exist in the source db - the sync script will be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(
START WITH 102),
TEXT VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
CONSTRAINT TEST_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
LOGGING;
```

We need that script without the `(START WITH 102)` part in it.

For a table that exist in both source and target db (with no other change than the sequence number) - the sync script will be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST
  MODIFY(ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(
  START WITH 114
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  CACHE 20
  NOCYCLE
  NOORDER));
```

The reality here is that this is a table that does not need an update, and I thought that `Ignore START WITH in sequence` would handle this, but apparently not.

Anyone out there have a solution for us?

Comment: I have also tried the compare tool from Red Gate (cost money). This tool ignores sequence when comparing tables.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I believe it is a very bad idea to use SQL Developer, or any other IDE tool for that matter, to create scripts to be deployed on Production. You are describing a clear case of lacking a real control version software, like GIT or SVN. You shouldn't need to compare between databases unless there is something wrong, but never for creating DDL scripts.

In this specific case, I would use DBMS_METADATA to create the DDLs

Example

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 increment by 1 ) , c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( null , 1 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> r
  1* insert into t values ( null , 1 )

1 row created.

SQL> r
  1* insert into t values ( null , 1 )

1 row created.

SQL> r
  1* insert into t values ( null , 1 )

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         3          1
         4          1
```

In this case SQL developer shows `start with 5`, because that is the next value of the identity column. You can use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` to get the right DDL without this clause.

```
SQL> begin
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
    DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','T') from dual

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','T')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SYS"."T"
   (    "C1" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99
99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "C2" NUMBER
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

There are several options to for example not get the storage attributes. I always use this one

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2       DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
     DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
  3    4       DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', true);
     DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
  END;
  /  5    6    7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','T') from dual ;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','T')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SYS"."T"
   (    "C1" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99
99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "C2" NUMBER
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;


SQL>
```

For comparison purposes, you might want to have a look into DBMS_COMPARISON

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS868

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. Does it also the case of tables that already exist on the target db, but with missing columns for instance?

Comment: No, it does not. You are describing a tool or software product, which is totally different from an utility to create right DDL scripts. There is no option in Oracle to do that, except if you use a third party software. For example, TOAD has an utility in built that synchronise environments by creating scripts to align them. Even so,  sometimes it fails in the way it creates the sync scripts, and you have to pay for Toad a lot of money. I would never ever used for Production, though. I was in a similar situation and I build a deployment software module in python & PL/SQL

Comment: I updated the answer that perhaps DBMS_COMPARISON is worth for you, but it will create the scripts in the same way as IDE tools you were using

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder, can you upvote the answer if you find it useful ? really appreciated